# Sharing an Apple ID with my son

Tags: iphone

I've noticed lately that my son's photo's are appearing in my album.  We've both had iPhones and shared my ID for years now so i can only assume something has changed within the software. We both have iPhone 7's.

How can i make it so we can't see each others photos but can still have our own and back them up to the cloud as we used to?

Comment: That sounds like Family Sharing in iCloud https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088

Comment: If you have he same id then there is really only one album. You should hae separate ids and use Family sharing